# Close event not working

Tags: c#, winforms

I want if user click the close button to close a `WinForm`, it will perform some work such as showing `MessageBox` message:

```
void frmMemberSearch_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("close message");
}
```

the about code does not work. Does anyone know what may be the problem?

Comment: Check method InitializeComponent(), the frmMemberSearch_FormClosing is added : this.frmMemberSearch_FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(frmMemberSearch_FormClosing);

Comment: It works by me, just tried it. What do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: @VinhVu where should i add the code?

Comment: just double click form closing event on Form Properties Tab. [check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZHXR.png)

Comment: @Badiparmagi thx it works

Comment: @Badiparmagi you should post this as an answer with the picture from your comment.

Comment: @MongZhu ok thanks. done

Answer (score 2):

just double click form closing event on Form Properties Tab.

[image]